Restarting the server of spring boot
I'm working on a project for uploading videos using spring boot, everything is working but when i upload a new video and i try to play i get that white label error and the status code is not found "404", but i restarted the server and everything worked properly so my question is how to do that without restarting the server knowing that im using intellij i have used this, in my application.properties and in my pom.xml i added these dependencies but it didn't work as well
 spring.devtools.restart.enabled= false`
   <dependency\>
       <artifactId\>spring-boot-starter-actuator\</artifactId\>
    </dependency\>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>


This is wrong: <artifactId\>spring-boot-starter-actuator\</artifactId\>. You have backslahes in wrong places. It should be: <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId\>.
To understand better on what you trying to do, you need to share the code, the exception you getting in the logs.

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message availableim not getting any logs

So it means the API does not exist, most likely. Without any code or anymore information, it is not possible to understand whats the issue. Even with a 404 I think , your logs should show this message that /api does not have a mapped handler.

You aren't writing to src/main/resources/static in your application, right?

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and format your question properly. It's not clear whether the backslashes are in your actual config file or your attempt to render them on this page.
